# Change background image on posts of x category

Tags: image, background, header, categories

im using different background image on each category wordpress like this see image: [Image Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF6uW.png) ,but for example: when i click on posts inside 'sport' category, header image of 'sport' category doesnt show, its work just on category but not on posts inside that category ,im using this code on 'top.php':

```
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();

if(    is_category( 'lajme' ) )  : ?>

<div id="header" style="background: #fff url(/wp-content/themes/veqinfo-theme/images/header-lajme.jpg) no-repeat 

top;">

<?php elseif( is_category( 'sport' ) )  : ?>

<div id="header" style="background: #fff url(/wp-content/themes/veqinfo-theme/images/-header-sport.jpg) no-repeat 

top;">


<?php elseif( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" 

class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()-

>height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to use css external file and trigger to your top.php you didn't closed that div tag

Comment: And use image tag not the image attribute it many times led to confusion

Comment: HEllo sir ,different background image on each category is working ,but problem is when i click on posts of that category then header back to normal like on homepage ,how to code to show header also on posts, not just on category ,here is my site: http://veqinfo.com/

Comment: Sorry erandi  I will not able to help you

Comment: Actually I never faced that problem

Comment: this is not a problem ,but i want to know the code , i have coded to show background image just on category ,but i don't know code to show background image on posts depending on category ,if you know coding you should help me

Comment: Actually where is your coding of post or this is your all coding you can have to post coding of post I will may be help you

Comment: Here is singe.php:
[Singe.php](http://pastebin.com/g0pANUXE)

and here top.php:
[top.php](http://pastebin.com/CqKspKcb)

Comment: A bit confusion I think this is

Comment: Ok mail me to admin@wphub.host56.com